# Number of count rows in mysql query store in $var in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hie Everyone!
My question is to count no. of rows from mysql query and store in `$var`.

Table - Table_nm / fields- UserID, Username, Serialno, Address.

php coding part:

```
$DB=Function();//this function is to connect to database.

$sql="select UserID,Username,Serialno,Address from Table_nm where UserID='1' and Username='name' and Serialno='20' and Address='Delhi' ";
```

If suppose for `$sql` there are 5 rows then count number 5 is store in `$var`.

How to write this query to count rows and number store in `$var` using PHP ?

Comment: $row_count = $mysql / $mysqli->num_rows 
num_rows are getting the number of rows, but it depends on how your whole MySQL query is made, could you please show all your 'Query' code ?

Comment: @Djip Yes In my code  use $mysql

Comment: Can you please show all your code ? Just the Part where you want to get the count of rows.

Comment: Can you send me your mail Id pls. I will give you the code part..not here because It is confidential.

Comment: I don't need any of your database connect code, keep that, or change it to something dummy when pasting in here.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM \`table_nm\` WHERE ...`?

Answer (score 3):

this might solve your problem

```
$sql=mysql_query("select UserID,Username,Serialno,Address from Table_nm where UserID='1' and Username='name' and Serialno='20' and Address='Delhi'");
$var = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Answer (score 0):

This will be correct if you have php < 5.5:

```
$sql="select UserID,Username,Serialno,Address from Table_nm where UserID='1' and Username='name' and Serialno='20' and Address='Delhi' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$var = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Mysql extension is depricated from php 5.5 so you need to use mysqli. Assuming that $BD is a mysqli connection it will be:

```
$sql="select UserID,Username,Serialno,Address from Table_nm where UserID='1' and Username='name' and Serialno='20' and Address='Delhi' ";
$result = $DB->query($sql))
$var = $result->num_rows;
```